# Answer undelete request

Tags: support

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57505/colorizing-tail-output-with-sed) about colorizing output which has been migrated from ServerFault and included an answer from my humble self, got this very answer deleted by a moderator.

Would you mind taking a second glance as the answer indeed *did* add another aspect which IMO has not been mentioned as of yet? Obviously, I would not have made the effort of writing it if I would not have attributed any value to the information provided.

Comment: I'm tempted to just merge those questions; I didn't because the newer one specifically asked about `sed`, but it looks like most answers ignored that anyway

Comment: @MichaelMrozek At ServerFault, it probably would have been closed as duplicate by now. But your practice would be different, I understand.

Answer (score 5):

I've converted it to a comment; is that better?

Comment: Yap, thanks. Although comments are ephermal, it surely is better than nothing.